# Struts2: Setting constant struts.action.extension to "," not working

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am working on `struts2-archetype-starter`. Got a demo `struts 2` project by executing:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=demoStrutsStarter -DartifactId=DemoStrutsStarter -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-starter
```

I modified my `struts.xml` and added a `struts.action.extension` constant declaration. Now it looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>

    <package name="myPackage" extends="struts-default">

        <default-action-ref name="index" />

        <action name="index" class="demoStrutsStarter.IndexAction">
            <result>/jsp/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="helloWorld" class="demoStrutsStarter.HelloWorldAction">
            <result name="input">/jsp/index.jsp</result>
            <result>/jsp/helloWorld.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

But, I am getting a 404 error when I type:

```
http://localhost:8080/DemoStrutsStarter/index
```

I am not sure where I am wrong. Can anybody please help me find out why I am unable to call actions without **.action** extension?

Comment: Is your app working w/o `struts.action.extension`?

Comment: Yes. `http://localhost:8080/DemoStrutsStarter/index.action` always displays the correct page, no matter if `struts.action.extension` is there or not. But, after setting it to ",", it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a namespace to your package:

```xml
<package name="myPackage" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" >
```

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/demo/index` still says `404 Not found` and `http://localhost:8080/demo/index.action` gives me the required form. I am testing it on Jetty: `mvn jetty:run`

Comment: Which Struts2 version?

Comment: Same version which comes along `mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=demoStrutsStarter -DartifactId=DemoStrutsStarter -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-starter`. How to check?

Comment: I found it here `struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html`. **The Starter Archetype** was providing me `spring and sitemesh integration` and i fell for it. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You're right... then let us continue this discussion in the other question

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out in both results**

result 1

```
<result>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</result>
```

result 2

```
<result>/WEB-INF/jsp/helloWorld.jsp</result>
```

else check your package name is correct or not.
by default, it's name **default**

try this links. it may help

1.[stack overflow link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068102/how-to-have-urls-without-a-suffix-e-g-action-in-struts-2)

2.[link 2 mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-remove-the-action-suffix-extension-in-struts-2/)

3.[stack overflow link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607075/struts2-action-extension-causing-css-javascript-and-struts-dojo-to-break)