# Tomcat 7.0.34: Taking too much time loading .action URLs

Tags: tomcat7

I am working on a `Struts 2` project. Tomcat is taking too long to load `.action` URLs (or Struts 2 actions). While loading them, it keeps on displaying several **mime type XML tags** as follows:-

```
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>book</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.framemaker</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>mmf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.smaf</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>mmd</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.chipnuts.karaoke-mmd</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>pptm</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  ...
```

I don't have any idea what plugin might have caused it. I tried to remove .action extension altogether but unable to do so [as asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745822/struts2-setting-constant-struts-action-extension-to-not-working). Can anybody please help solve this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to RESTART FROM SCRATCH.

Use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), create an empty project by running a [Struts2 Maven Archetype](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html).

I suggest you the [Blank Convention Archetype](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html#Struts2MavenArchetypes-TheBlankConventionArchetype%28struts2-archetype-convention%29):

```maven
mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=com.mycompany.mysystem \
                          -DartifactId=myWebApp \
                          -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts \
                          -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-convention \
                          -DarchetypeVersion=<CURRENT_STRUTS_VERSION> \
                          -DremoteRepositories=http://struts.apache.org
```

Generally, but this depends on the type of your project, the only plugins you should care about at the beginning should be the Convention-Plugin, the Json-Plugin, and the jQuery-Plugin.

Be sure to take all the **latest** versions of each library, ensure that all the versions are aligned too.

Finally, check out the [project dependencies](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/dependency-management.html) on the Struts2 page, and be sure to include everything, and in the right version.

Comment: I used `struts2-archetype-blank` and added sitemesh afterwards which is working just fine.